# firebase info/connected onDataChange 1 minute false no response

Tags: android, firebase, connection

I have the following code called in `onCreate` to keep track of whether the user is connected to firebase/can connect to firebase:

```
    DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
    connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            connected = false; // not called in the observations below
        }
    });
```

**Observed behavior:**

A. When initialized:

- onDataChange is called with connected set to false
- onDataChange is called with connected set to true quickly thereafter (assuming had internet connection)

B. Before the 1 minute:

- Turning off wifi or data will cause connected set to false
- Turning on wifi or data will cause connected set to true

C. At 1 minute

- connected set to false via onDataChange

D. After 1 minute

- onDataChange is not called regardless of going on wifi/data

**Expected behavior:**

A'. Same as A

B'. Same as B

C'. Nothing

D'. Same as B.

I've seen other questions regarding losing authentication, but I haven't seen auth issues in my logs. Additionally the precise time of one minute seems very specific and was not seen in other similar question/answers.
Note that I'm using firebase 9.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what I have observed on 9.0.2, the connection is closed after one minute when it is not needed.  To leave the connection open would needlessly drain the battery.

A connection is needed when:

1. `DatbaseReference.setValue()` is executed.
2. `Query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` is executed
3. A `ValueEventListener` or `ChildEventListener` has been added and not removed

After a connection has been closed, one of the listed events will cause it to reopen.  For events 1 and 2, the connection will close again after one minute.  When a listener has been added (not for single value), the connection remains open until the listener is removed.

Comment: Does the listener on ".info/connected" not count as a listener that requires the web-socket to stay open?

Comment: From what I have observed, no, it does not count.